# Jekyll Emails: can I have multiple email campaigns in one jekyll project

Tags: jekyll

Is it possible to create folders within the `_includes` folder of a Jekyll project to separate multiple email campaigns for one single company? Everything needs to be more organized, each company having their own separate folder inside `_includes` and not having to create one Jekyll project for each campaign. Having  them all inside one big Jekyll project is what I'm looking for.

New to Jekyll. noob question. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I am running multi niche blog in Jekyll, and here what I have done in my website.

I have created multiple layout for different type of pages, for example, here I created blogger.html layout (May be you are using default post or page layout)

```
---
layout: null
---
<html>

  {% include head.html %}

  <body>
    {% include header/blogger.html %}
    <section class="container">
        <div class ="content row">

            <section class="main col col-lg-7">
                 <div class="post">
                  <header class="post-header">
                    <h1 class="post-title">{{ page.title }}</h1>
                  </header>
                  <article class="post-content">
                    {{ content }}
                  </article>
                </div>
            </section>

        </div>
    </section>

    {% include footer.html %}

  </body>

</html>
```

As you can see(after `<body>` tag), I have added blogger file into _include folder, **so yes, you can add any file/folder into _include folder, just make sure, the relative path is correct.**